# activerecord: check first X chars of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to check the first two chars of a number straight in my model. First I define the number of the current logged in user (devise):

```
user_number = current_user.number.first(2)
```

then I want to take that value and check it within a where statement in a "number" mobel, so I tried this

```
@numbers = Number.where(:number_value.first(2) => user_number)
```

which is obviously the same as

```
@numbers = Number.where(:number_value.first(2) => current_user.number.first(2))
```

No, that does not work.

How can I check the first 2 chars of the :number_value column in my model?
Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution (SQLite)

```
@numbers = Number.where("number_value like '" + current_user.number.first(2) + "%'")
```

since this is not lazy loading I'm not convinced yet that it is the smartest solution. if you know any better, would be cool if you can share

Answer (score 1):

First, you should read the [ActiveRecord query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). I'd also imagine that there's a much more straight forward way for you to accomplish your goal.

But, to answer your specific question, here's an approach that'd work with Postgresql.

```
Number.where("number_value::text like ?", current_user.number.to_s[0,2] + "%")
```

Comment: that looks good, but what about sqlite? using it on dev. postgres only on production.
sure, I read the ActiveRecord guide but did not find much :/

Comment: You probably should read more closely and get familiar with the basics of ActiveRecord and ruby.

Comment: I made it work (see above). When pushing to heroku (which uses postgres) I got my sqlite statement not working obviously. Using yours does work. But how can I tell my script "use this statement on dev and this statement on production"?